# How to show multiple Twitter Bootstrap navbar's on the same page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to show more than one navbar on a given page?
I'd like to have an inverted navbar fixed to the top, and then on certain pages have a second fixed navbar right under it as an additional information header.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure you can have 2 navbars. You may have to tweak the code to get it the way you want...

### [**Working Example**](http://bootply.com/61104)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <a class="brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem that I've having is that if I apply navbar-fixed-top to both of them, the second one is on top of (z axis) the first one.

Comment: Ok, I've got it figured out. I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it. http://bootply.com/61112

Comment: Please close thread, because bootply examples are no longer working.

Comment: The bootply links are working fine. I've added the code to the answer.